# Python extract data from xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, urllib

I'm trying to get the values from this web page:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfVwHistoryDetail xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<vwHistoryDetail>
<idVariable>2561</idVariable>
<DateTime>2020-12-01T00:00:00</DateTime>
<idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
<Value>28671555</Value>
<ValueDetail>4415</ValueDetail>
</vwHistoryDetail>
<vwHistoryDetail>
<idVariable>2561</idVariable>
<DateTime>2020-12-02T00:00:00</DateTime>
<idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
<Value>28675970</Value>
<ValueDetail>4279</ValueDetail>
</vwHistoryDetail>
<vwHistoryDetail>
<idVariable>2561</idVariable>
<DateTime>2020-12-03T00:00:00</DateTime>
<idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
<Value>28680249</Value>
<ValueDetail>3975</ValueDetail>
</vwHistoryDetail>
<vwHistoryDetail>
<idVariable>2561</idVariable>
<DateTime>2020-12-04T00:00:00</DateTime>
<idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
<Value>28684224</Value>
<ValueDetail>4236</ValueDetail>
</vwHistoryDetail>
</ArrayOfVwHistoryDetail>
```

I tested with this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib import request


url = "http://SomeSite/WebService.asmx/LoadVariableHistory?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&variableName=CBT2_G_PRM_FB2&startDateTime=2020-12-01&endDateTime=2020-12-02&sampling=3"

print ("Obter: ", url)
html = request.urlopen(url)
data = html.read()
print("Obtido: ",len(data),"caracteres")

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
results = tree.findall('Value')
for i in results:
  print(i)
```

I hid the full URL for safety reasons.
What I'm doing wrong to not get the values? I need to get thru this part so I can build a dictionary with DataTime : Value

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think you want the HTML of the page...if you use the `requests` library, you can get your data like so: `requests.get(url).content`. Note that you will have to install requests vie pip or some such. The XML file probably won't be parsed correctly with the "This XML file does not appear to have..." in the beginning.

Comment: when I print `requests.get(url).content`, I get this: `b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<ArrayOfVwHistoryDetail xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">\r\n  <vwHistoryDetail>\r\n    <idVariable>2561</idVariable>\r\n 
   <DateTime>2020-12-01T00:00:00</DateTime>\r\n    <idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>\r\n    <Value>28671555</Value>\r\n    <ValueDetail>4415</ValueDetail>\r\n  </vwHistoryDetail>\r\n</ArrayOfVwHistoryDetail>'` I still get no value.

Comment: That looks correct.  XML does not care about whitespace such as \r\n which are just line breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues emerge in your current implementation:

- Your XML contains an default namespace, `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` which requires you to define a prefix in order to parse node content; `findall` maintains a *namespaces* argument.
- Your path expression assumes `Value` is a child of root. You need to employ a double slash path, `.//`, since `Value` is a descendant of root.
- You need to extract the `text` of iterator variable. Otherwise, you will return `<Element ... >` object which is usually not useful in end-use needs.

Consider adjustment

```py
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
nmsp = {'doc': 'http://tempuri.org/'}                         # NAMESPACE PREFIX ASSIGNMENT
results = tree.findall('.//doc:Value', namespaces = nmsp)     # NAMESPACE PREFIX USE WITH './/' PATH 
for i in results:
  print(i.text)                                               # RETRIEVE TEXT VALUE

# 28671555
# 28675970
# 28680249
# 28684224
```

Even better, return a dictionary of `.Value` and its siblings with list/dict comprehension (where `split` removes default namespace in dict keys):

```py
data_list_of_dicts = [{i.tag.split('}')[-1]: i.text for i in hd} 
                        for hd in tree.findall('.//doc:vwHistoryDetail', namespaces = nmsp)]

print(data_list_of_dicts)
# [{'idVariable': '2561', 'DateTime': '2020-12-01T00:00:00', 'idPeriodType': '1', 'Value': '28671555', 'ValueDetail': '4415'}, 
#  {'idVariable': '2561', 'DateTime': '2020-12-02T00:00:00', 'idPeriodType': '1', 'Value': '28675970', 'ValueDetail': '4279'}, 
#  {'idVariable': '2561', 'DateTime': '2020-12-03T00:00:00', 'idPeriodType': '1', 'Value': '28680249', 'ValueDetail': '3975'}, 
#  {'idVariable': '2561', 'DateTime': '2020-12-04T00:00:00', 'idPeriodType': '1', 'Value': '28684224', 'ValueDetail': '4236'}]
```

For time-keyed value dictionary:

```py
time_value_dict = {hd.find('doc:DateTime', namespaces=nmsp).text: 
                   hd.find('doc:Value', namespaces=nmsp).text 
                      for hd in tree.findall('.//doc:vwHistoryDetail', namespaces=nmsp)}

print(time_value_dict)
# {'2020-12-01T00:00:00': '28671555', 
#  '2020-12-02T00:00:00': '28675970', 
#  '2020-12-03T00:00:00': '28680249', 
#  '2020-12-04T00:00:00': '28684224'}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/OQXJW96665)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, I tried to change your code with the suggestions from @balderman to just get the DataTime : Value Pair: `tree = ET.fromstring(data)
nmsp = {'doc': 'http://tempuri.org/'}                         # NAMESPACE PREFIX ASSIGNMENT
results = tree.findall('.//doc:Value', namespaces = nmsp)     # NAMESPACE PREFIX USE WITH './/' PATH 


DataTimeValue_dict = [{i.find('DateTime').text: i.find('Value').text for i in hd} 
                        for hd in tree.findall('.//doc:vwHistoryDetail', namespaces = nmsp)]`

Comment: Output:
  File "g:/My Drive/Projectos/Python/teste/get.py", line 19, in <module>
    DataTimeValue_dict = [{i.find('DateTime').text: i.find('Value').text for i in hd}
  File "g:/My Drive/Projectos/Python/teste/get.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
    DataTimeValue_dict = [{i.find('DateTime').text: i.find('Value').text for i in hd}
  File "g:/My Drive/Projectos/Python/teste/get.py", line 19, in <dictcomp>
    DataTimeValue_dict = [{i.find('DateTime').text: i.find('Value').text for i in hd}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
PS G:\My Drive\Projectos\Python\teste>

Comment: @NunoFélix, your dictionary comprehension is incorrect. Try `d = {hd.find('./doc:DateTime', namespaces=nmsp).text: hd.find('./doc:Value', namespaces=nmsp).text for hd in tree.findall('.//doc:vwHistoryDetail', namespaces=nmsp)}`

Comment: You need to pass `namespace` in `.find` just as you did with `.findall`. See edit and demo update.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait and every one o helped me, finally, it worked the way I was looking for. I have just started learning Python at Udemy, so I'm making a lot of newbie mistakes.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for detail in tree.findall('vwHistoryDetail'):
  v = detail.find('Value').text
  print(v)
```

You are better off looping through an object and extracting children elements, instead of just grabbing the children directly since Value may be a tag reused in different parts of the document

Comment: I tested your suggestions but still, no value is printed. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

#
xml = '''<ArrayOfVwHistoryDetail xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <vwHistoryDetail>
      <idVariable>2561</idVariable>
      <DateTime>2020-12-01T00:00:00</DateTime>
      <idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
      <Value>28671555</Value>
      <ValueDetail>4415</ValueDetail>
   </vwHistoryDetail>
   <vwHistoryDetail>
      <idVariable>2561</idVariable>
      <DateTime>2020-12-02T00:00:00</DateTime>
      <idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
      <Value>28675970</Value>
      <ValueDetail>4279</ValueDetail>
   </vwHistoryDetail>
   <vwHistoryDetail>
      <idVariable>2561</idVariable>
      <DateTime>2020-12-03T00:00:00</DateTime>
      <idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
      <Value>28680249</Value>
      <ValueDetail>3975</ValueDetail>
   </vwHistoryDetail>
   <vwHistoryDetail>
      <idVariable>2561</idVariable>
      <DateTime>2020-12-04T00:00:00</DateTime>
      <idPeriodType>1</idPeriodType>
      <Value>28684224</Value>
      <ValueDetail>4236</ValueDetail>
   </vwHistoryDetail>
</ArrayOfVwHistoryDetail>'''
xml = re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', xml, count=1)
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {v.find('DateTime').text: v.find('Value').text for v in root.findall('.//vwHistoryDetail')}
print(data)
```

output

```
{'2020-12-01T00:00:00': '28671555', '2020-12-02T00:00:00': '28675970', '2020-12-03T00:00:00': '28680249', '2020-12-04T00:00:00': '28684224'}
```

Comment: [Running regex on XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422451)? All compliant DOM libraries should handle default namespaces and not need to remove it from tree.